# 0 is added but not shown as two digit when converted to int 

Tags: java, date, printing, integer

I want to add a `0` in front of a date if it is single digit. So I made a code:

```
public class Zero {

    /**
    * @param args
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String zero="0";
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        int day1 = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        String seven1=Integer.toString(day1);
        System.out.println(""+seven1);
        System.out.println(""+day1);
        String added=zero.concat(seven1);
        System.out.println(""+added);
        int change=Integer.parseInt(added);
        System.out.println(""+change);
    }

}
```

So when I print `change` it prints only `7` not `07`. Actually I want to make the `int` `07` instead of `7`. So what modification should be done to print `07`?

**NB**- I did not mention the `if-else` checking for single-digit or multi-digit date intentionally as there is no problem with it!

Comment: Do not reinvent the wheel. See the answers that talk about `SimpleDateFormat`.

Answer (score 5):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for formatting a date.

Your pattern will be `dd`.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this using the `SimpleDateFormat`

```
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd").format(new Date()));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String addZero(String input) {
    if(input.length() == 1)
        return "0" + input;
    return input;
}
```

That method will only add a zero to the begining of a string if it's 1 digit, so if you hand it "1", itll return "01", if you hand it "11", itll return "11". I think thats what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using a [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) object? This will give you a high degree of control of the formatting. The text `dd` will provide you with a zero-padded day value.

Answer (score 0):

Try using http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

the correct usage is something along the lines of

```
int day = Calendar.Day_OF_Month;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("00"); 
System.out.println(df.format(day));
```

Also, dont forget that java months start at 0 :/

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution would be:

```
int change = Integer.parseInt(added);
if (change < 10) {
   System.out.println("0" + change);
} else {
   System.out.println(change);
}
```

However a better solution would be to use the [NumberFormat class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html).

Comment: I don't want to print only. I want to make the `int` as `07`