# Save an integer in two digit format in a variable in Java

Tags: java, numbers

How can I store an integer in two digit format in Java? Like can I set

```
int a=01;
```

and print it as `01`? Also, not only printing, if I say `int b=a;`, `b` should also print its value as `01`.

Comment: Integers are integers. *Assuming no octal notation* (which there is in Java literals) then 1 = 01 = 001 = .. You are looking to turn the **integer** into the **String** with that format ..

Comment: First of all, int can represent value much larger than 99. If you need such representation, make your own class.

Comment: I think you are looking for something like this: [Format an Integer using Java String Format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034523/format-an-integer-using-java-string-format)

Comment: possible duplicate of [0 is added but not shown as two digit when converted to int ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850609/0-is-added-but-not-shown-as-two-digit-when-converted-to-int)

Comment: @Mist4u, have you ever worked with COBOL? :-D

Comment: @TassosBassoukos, Nah! But please let me know how is COBOL funny?

Comment: @Mistu4u Well, in COBOL there are number types that are preformatted (that is, the number type itself defines that f.e. this value is a 2-digit decimal number that has leading zeroes).

Answer (score 84, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
int a = 1;
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("00");
String aFormatted = formatter.format(a);

System.out.println(aFormatted);
```

Or, more briefly:

```
int a = 1;
System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("00").format(a));
```

An int just stores a quantity, and 01 and 1 represent the same quantity so they're stored the same way.

[DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) builds a String that represents the quantity in a particular format.

Answer (score 20):

```
// below, %02d says to java that I want my integer to be formatted as a 2 digit representation
String temp = String.format("%02d", yourIntValue);
// and if you want to do the reverse
int i = Integer.parse(temp);

// 2 -> 02 (for example)
```

Comment: Should be "%02d" instead of "%2d"

Answer (score 6):

This is not possible, because an integer is an integer. But you can format the Integer, if you want ([DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)).

Answer (score 5):

look at the  below format its work above format can work for me

System.out.printf("%02d", myNumber)